# Map Projection with correct distances?

Tags: coordinate-system

Is there a map projection where the Euclidean distance between any 2 points is the same as the great circle distance/real world distance between the 2 points?

I know as an image, it might look funny, but for doing calculations, it might be useful.

Comment: Wouldn't it? Unfortunately it is impossible to calculate a general equidistant projection of a spherical body onto a plane. You can have equidistance as a property between two defined points, resulting in equal distances to great circles in a certain direction only. The [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Map_projection#Equidistant) article has some useful info on these.